# export USERNAME=root in zsh gives permission error

Tags: shell, zsh

When I run

```
export USERNAME=root
```

in `zsh` it gives me the following error.

```
zsh: failed to change group ID: operation not permitted
```

Any idea why?

PS: I did not manually run this initially, but I came across this when my `vim-dispatch` plugin threw this error while running a command in `vim`. Afterwards I was able to reproduce this by just running it in any `zsh` shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [parameter `USERNAME`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-USERNAME) corresponds to the real user ID of the shell process. Modifying it also changes the real user ID, effectively changing the permissions of the running shell process. This is of course only possible, if the original user has sufficient privileges. In most cases this probably means that only *root* is allowed to assign to `USERNAME`, while any other accounts are not permitted.

For example, consider this shell session:

```
root@host# echo $USERNAME $UID $EUID $GID $EGID
root 0 0 0 0
root@host# USERNAME=adaephon
adaephon@host% echo $USERNAME $UID $EUID $GID $EGID
adaephon 1000 1000 1000 1000
adaephon@host% USERNAME=root
zsh: failed to change group ID: operation not permitted
adaephon@host% echo $USERNAME $UID $EUID $GID $EGID
adaephon 1000 1000 1000 1000
```

Starting out as *root*, I can easily drop my privileges to my normal user account. But I cannot switch back to *root* as *adaephon* lacks the necessary privileges.